# Express.js keep loading and loading when error inside generator

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I noticed that while there is an error inside generator, express.js keep processing without stopping it. So, I am not able to find the actual error. My question is: how to stop express.js and output error when there an error in generator.

My codes

**Controller.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {wrap: async} = require('co');
const Post = require('../models/Post');
//.... there are more modules.

const getPosts = async(function* (req, res) {
  const page = (req.query.page > 0 ? req.query.page : 1) - 1;
  const limit = 5;
  const options = {
    limit: limit,
    page: page
  };

  const posts = yield Post.list(options);
  const count = yield Post.count();
  console.log(posts);

  res.render('posts/index', {
    title: 'Home',
    posts: posts,
    page: page + 1,
    pages: Math.ceil(count / limit)
  });
});

app.get('/', getPosts);
```

**Post.js**

```
//.. more codes

postSchema.static.list = function (options) {
  const criteria = options.criteria || {};
  const page = options.page || 0;
  const limit = options.limit || 30;
  return this.find(criteria)
    .populate('user', 'name userlogin profile email')
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .limit(limit)
    .skip(limit * page)
    .exec();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an typo in Post.js. `postSchema.static.list` should be `postSchema.statics.list` (statics not static).

Try wrapping `yield` inside try and catch.

```
const getPosts = async(function* (req, res, next) {
  const page = (req.query.page > 0 ? req.query.page : 1) - 1;
  const limit = 5;
  const options = {
    limit: limit,
    page: page
  };
  try {
    const posts = yield Post.list(options);
    const count = yield Post.count();
    console.log(posts);

    res.render('posts/index', {
      title: 'Home',
      posts: posts,
      page: page + 1,
      pages: Math.ceil(count / limit)
    });
  }catch(err){
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am so dumb. Thanks a lot.